# python script fails to start in screen, in systemd. no error

Tags: systemd, python, services, python3

I wrote a python script that I would like to launch inside of screen

```
screen -d -m /usr/bin/python3 /home/kermit/active-climateMngr.py
```

which works just fine at the command line but when I try to begin it in systemd as a service, no screen session ever launches.

.service config:

```
[Unit]
Description=Test Service
After=multi-user.target
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -d -m /usr/bin/python3 /home/kermit/active-climateMngr.py
StandardInput=tty-force

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

systemd:

```
kermit@minnow:~ $ sudo service active-climateMngr.py status
● active-climateMngr.py.service - Test Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/active-climateMngr.py.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2021-02-20 08:58:46 CST; 4min 7s ago
  Process: 14373 ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -d -m /usr/bin/python3 /home/kermit/active-climateMngr.py (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 14373 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 20 08:58:46 minnow.coinz.com systemd[1]: Started Test Service.
Feb 20 08:58:46 minnow.coinz.com systemd[1]: active-climateMngr.py.service: Succeeded.
```

screen:

```
kermit@minnow:~ $ screen -ls
No Sockets found in /run/screen/S-kermit.
```

How do I get systemd to launch a custom pythons script, in a screen session?

I was able to get the script to work without screen in systemd before, but now that no long works either.

I am using

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

with every change.

Comment: The systemd unit runs as root (unless otherwise specified with User=). You are trying to attach as a regular user.

Comment: @jsbillings I'm not following you. "attach". I'm not even running 'screen -x <foo>' yet. What do you mean?

Comment: For one thing, your screen session detaches immediately with -d -m, and you have Type=simple, so it doesn’t track the forked process.  Also, your service runs as root.  You are looking for screen sessions as ‘kermit’ with screen -ls, so it isn’t a surprise it isn’t finding root’s sessions.

Comment: Where am I trying to run it as a user? it in a user directory, but I am expecting root to run it.

Comment: The answer has more details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A systemd unit with `Type=simple` is expected to not fork into the background, but `screen -d -m` creates a new detached session in the background and exits. This causes systemd to regard the unit as dead and either kill the detached session or lose track of it. Use `-D -m` instead:

```
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -D -m …
```

The difference between those two options is explained in the manpage [screen(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen):

> **-d -m**   Start screen in "detached" mode. This creates a new session but doesn't attach to it. This is useful for system startup scripts.
> **-D -m**   This also starts screen in "detached" mode, but doesn't fork a new process. The command exits if the session terminates.

As the screen session runs as root if you don't include e.g. `User=kermit` in your systemd unit, you'll need to use `sudo screen -ls` to see the session.

Comment: After changing to -D, I was able to see that me screen session was really starting and just needed to 'sudo screen -ls' to see it. I'm good now. Thank you.